# laravel 5.5 resource restful API

Tags: php, laravel, rest, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I am trying to create an API for my app so that I can share the endpoint and have one app as the core application with business logic and the other can connect with an exposed endpoint to consume the function as services.

I am getting an error when I try to hit the endpoint.

Below is my **route/api.php**

```
<?php

use App\PostModell;
use App\Http\Resources\PostModellResource;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
Route::get( '/cars',function(){
    return new PostModellResource(PostModell::all());
});
```

My resource class looks like

```
class PostModellResource extends Resource
{
         public function toArray($request)
    {
        return
        [
            'id'=>$this->id,
            'title'=>$this->title,
            'body'=>$this->body,
            'created_at' => $this->created_at,
            'updated_at' => $this->updated_at,

        ];          
    }
```

The error is

`Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.`

Comment: which url you are trying to hit?? show us your complete url with domain name that you tried and getting error like `www.google.com/lists`

Comment: This is the URL am hitting http://127.0.0.1:8000/cars

Comment: @DENNISKITHINJI since it's in the  `routes/app.php`, you need to use `https://127.0.0.1:8000/api/cars`

Comment: @Sohel0415   This works https://127.0.0.1:8000/api/cars but am also getting a new error "Property [title] does not exist on this collection instance."  this is happening to all my model coloums

Comment: @DENNISKITHINJI see my updated answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `api` prefix-

```
127.0.0.1:8000/api/cars
```

To convert collection of resources, you need to use [collection()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-resources#concept-overview) method-

```
return PostModellResource::collection(PostModell::all());
```

Answer (score 3):

Since the route in `api` routes, use this URI:

```
https://example.com/api/cars
```

Also, as I'm showing in my best practices repo [you shouldn't put the logic into routes](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices#other-good-practices), move all the logic in a controller instead.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using Laravel `api.php` then you have to use `api` prefix,

Or if your using Lumen `web.php` then you can call it directly or you can define api prefix as per your requirement.

in Laravel : `localhost:8000/api/yoururl`

in Lumen : `localhost/yoururl`

Answer (score 1):

All routes in the api have the prefix path of `/api` (by default). So in your case, you should access it via: http://YOURAPPURL/api/cars

You might want to check your `App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider@mapApiRoutes` for more information.